# See if an item in a list is in another item in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and have just started learning Python. I wanted to create a small program that simply detects if you enter in a "bad word" in your entry.

```
name = input ('Please enter your name. ')
badword=['foo', 'bar']
if name in badword:
    print ('No.')
else:
    print ('Yes')
```

This way doesn't work as it's taking the entirety of what was entered and is searching the list for that entry. And if I try to us:

```
if badword in name:
```

Then I just get an error. I could call each part of the list, but that's a lot of code especially if you're entering in different types of bad words, and that would just get lengthy for something I know I can do in less code. A little lost here, and google searches have come up dry.

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop over the `badword` list to test *each word*:

```
for word in badword:
    if word in name:
        print('No.')
        break
else:
    print('Yes.')
```

The `else` clause is part of the `for` statement; it is executed when the loop was *not* interrupted by a `break` statement, so in this case if none of the values from `badword` matched.

This can be shortened with the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a generator expression:

```
if any(word in name for word in badword):
    print('No.')
else:
    print('Yes.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt: `if badword in name` is almost right. You need to check every item in badword - something like this:

```
if any( [ word for word in badword if word in name ] ):
    print( 'No' )
    break
else:
    print( 'Yes' )
```

`any` returns true if any of the conditions match. The bit between `[]` is a list comprehension, which returns a new list. e.g:

```
print( [ word for word in badword ] )
```

The last `if word in name` is a condition for addign items to that new list, so only items for which the condition is `True` end up in the new list.

Comment: No need to create an intermediate list in memory if you're not going to use it, `any` works fine with a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = [" some BAD sentense ", "some right sentense"]
bad_words_list = ["bad", "wrong"]

def check(enter):
    """Check for word in bad words list. Note, check process not key sensitive.

    Return True if sentense contains bad word."""
    sentense = enter.lower().split()
    for word in bad_words_list:
        if word.lower() in sentense:
            return False
    return True

print "Is sentense bad? " + str(check(inputs[0]))
print "Is sentense bad? " + str(check(inputs[1]))
```

Test it:

```
$ python test.py
Is sentense bad: False
Is sentense bad: True
```